# Searching audio extensions in a folder

Tags: batch

I'm trying to check in a folder of audio files that the mp3, flac and wav extensions DO NOT EXIST. If none of the three exist, I send a message that there are no audio files in the folder.

I made a batch file using as an example the FOR command I found in this post: 
[loop-through-files-in-a-folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40885418/loop-through-files-in-a-folder-and-check-if-they-have-different-extensions)

however, when I run the batch file, the message appears even though there are audio files inside the folder, see the code below:

```
@echo off
chcp 65001
cls
ENDLOCAL
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS

For %%A In ("C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\Audio Folder\*.mp3" "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\Audio Folder\*.flac" "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\Audio Folder\*.wav") Do (
    (If Not Exist "%%~xA" Set "flag=MISSING")
)

set "ESC="
for /F %%d in ('echo prompt $E ^| cmd') do (set "ESC=%%d")

If Defined flag ( 
 SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
 echo %ESC%[31mThere are no audio extensions in the folder! Exit and check which files are in the folder. (e=exit^)%ESC%[0m
 SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
 set /p r=
 IF /i "%r%"=="e" goto notfound 
)

:notfound
echo.
exit
```

I did several tests and I couldn't, I don't know if I made a mistake in the for command.
How can I check my folder and verify that there is no file with an audio extension?

Comment: `"%%~xA"` indeed (most probably) is not existent. the `~x` modifier returns the extension only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your FOR command is flawed. Besides executing for each file,
I don't like the part of "If Not Exist".

This (untested) code should do better :

```
IF EXIST "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\Audio Folder\*.mp3" SET "found=FOUND"
IF EXIST "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\Audio Folder\*.flac" SET "found=FOUND"
IF EXIST "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\Audio Folder\*.wav" SET "found=FOUND"

IF NOT DEFINED found (
```

Comment: Perfect! it works. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think a `for` loop is overkill here. Just try to list files and act according to the errorlevel:

```
pushd "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\Audio Folder\"
dir /b *.wav *.mp3 *.flac >nul 2>&1 && goto :found
popd
echo no files present
goto :eof
:found
popd
echo at least one audio file present.
```

`&&` acts as "if previous file was successful (found file(s)) then". If you need the opposite, `||` is "if previous command failed (no file found) then"

Comment: It works too. thanks.